# Set text format in footer

Tags: excel, vba

Can you change the font format of a value you add into the footer of a document ?
I could already achieve the value itself but can't seems to find the way to change the format of it.

This is the code I have:

```
Sub SetValueInFooter()
Dim WorkRng As Range
On Error Resume Next
'make variable with the number
Dim TextINeed As String
TextINeed = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
'add the number into the footer left
Application.ActiveSheet.PageSetup.LeftFooter = TextINeed
'define style of the number (this 'with' section has no effect, text stays black font size 10)
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup.LeftFooter
  .Font.Size = 8
  .Font.Color = RGB(192, 80, 77)
End With
End Sub
```

Thanks for your time & help

Comment: Was the macro recorder helpful at all? Also a blanket `On Error Resume Next` is normally bad practice, as it's just hiding potential errors; it should be removed.

Comment: @BigBen I removed the "On Error Resume Next" and I had an error on the With ActiveSheet.PageSetup.LeftFooter ... part.
I removed it and code is running well, except that the color and font size isn't changing obviously :)
While using the macro recorder I have ' With Selection.Font 
        .Color = -11710272
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With' but normally the text isn't selected obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page setting is different from that of the normal cell. It is helpful to record macros to identify patterns.

```
Sub SetValueInFooter()
    Dim WorkRng As Range
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim TextINeed As String
    Set Ws = ActiveSheet
    'On Error Resume Next
    'make variable with the number
    
    TextINeed = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
    'add the number into the footer left
    'Application.ActiveSheet.PageSetup.LeftFooter = TextINeed
    'define style of the number (this 'with' section has no effect, text stays black font size 10)
    
    With Ws.PageSetup
        .LeftFooter = "&8&kc0504d" & TextINeed '<~~  8:=font.size  /  c0504d:=font.color (html color) / TextINeed:= text
    End With
End Sub
```